# Checking with co-authors on status of a not-yet-submitted paper?

Tags: publications, etiquette

In the spring, I briefly helped with a decently sized project. Shortly after it wrapped, I was asked if I wanted to be co-author on the paper being written on the project. I agreed, and subsequently haven't heard anything back. It's a database project so there will be a long list of co-authors, and I don't want to be a bother, but I also don't want to be left off.

Is five months a reasonable time to wait before asking after status?

Comment: Are you sure the paper was sent out to a journal or a conference?

Comment: When I last spoke with them it sounded like a done deal. That's part of what I wanted to check on.

Comment: I usually have more problems with co-authors who fail to check in with me.  I say check once a month, and if you want it to get done, offer to help.

Answer (score 3):

Publications plans can end up going into limbo for a long time.  In my experience, this can be especially true for publications with lots of authors, because you can easily end up in a situation where nobody's really stepping forward to get it written, or where everybody thinks somebody else is the one dealing with the current road-block.  One paper that I am an author on spent *three years* in un-submitted limbo for such reasons.

As such, checking in every few months is totally reasonable, as you may in fact provide the stimulus to keep it moving forward.  Be warned, however, that if it's ended up in limbo and if you actually care about the paper, that you may well find yourself one of the ones getting handed tasks for actually writing it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jake Beal that too much nagging might result in you doing all the work. So I would suggest asking a rather innocent question related to the paper, e.g. about the content of a section you had little to do with, some formulation questions, or whether you can give a small talk about your work somewhere (e.g. the local seminar, not a conference). Chances are pretty high that you will get the information you want without taking over too much obligation.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd put the same value qualifiers on the situation that you do.  If one pesters without wanting to do the work, then yes, it's nagging.  But if you're willing to end up doing a lot of the work, you might end up in a more prominent authorship position, having a really interesting experience, and learning a lot in the process!